# Concerns on security function within Websphere Application Server

Tags: websphere

i'm confused with the relationship between the file `security.xml` and `inbound/outbound SSL` from attached picture within websphere application server.

file `security.xml` locates under this path `PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/CELL_NAME`

if i make security disabled by setting the **`enable`** property as **`false`** from that secuirty.xml, is the SSL function also being disabled? that also means, if **`enable`** set as **`true**`, that SSL enabled accordingly.

Please correct me if i'm understanding wrongly. 
[image]

Comment: No, if you disable security in security.xml it does not switch off SSL

Comment: @DavanumSrinivas-dims but if so, why the SSL issue can disappear when i disable the security in security.xml? Actually, we've got the websphere SSL issue between dmgr and nodeagnet leading the nodeagent status can not be shown correctly through admin console. However, if i disable the security, both the SSL error and unsync status issue have gone

Comment: what you have is a problem federating nodes. See tip here -http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2009/09/enablign-administrative-security.html - on how to enable disable security from the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

In general security and SSL are not the same but there is a strong relationship there.

If security is enabled then SSL might be enforced in certain communications. As Davanum srinivas mentioned, the communication between the node agents and dmgr start using SSL. The deployment descriptors entries which mandate confidentiality would start enforcing when security is enabled etc.

HTH

Comment: thanks for your answer. as you mentioned, once security enabled, SSL would be working accordingly. then how about disabling security, would that cause SSL disabled as well? or as Davanum said, that disabling operation will never switch off SSL? Thanks